# Why am I not able to add submenus to this CSS HTML code?

Tags: html, css

In it I just added  a submenu using  but it seems the CSS code did not allow this and I got nothing. I am getting this code from a template I found online.
http://way2themes.com/blogger-templates/spraymag.zip

There are more templates like this. So I am facing a common problem in them all. How do i isolate the code that allows me to add sub menus, sub sub menus?

This is the CSS that I am working on.

```
#header .menu ul li {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
height: 40px;
border-right: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
border-top: none;
}

#header .menu ul li a{
padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
display: block;
border: none !important;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: inherit;
border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
color: #999;
}
#header .menu ul li a:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,200,0.1);  color: #FFF;  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#main-menu ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.main-navigation-wrapper {
    display: block;  margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;  margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto;  
}
ul#main-nav {
    display: block;  background: #363D40;  border-top: solid 5px #666;  border-top-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);  padding-right: 40px;  min-height: 40px;  margin-bottom: 0 !important;  box-shadow: inset 0 -20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.09);  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;  transition: all 0.2s ease;
    zoom: 1;
}
#main-nav > li {
    float: left;  display: inline-block;  position: relative;  border-top: solid 5px transparent;  
    margin-top: -5px;
    line-height: 21px;
}
#main-nav > li > a:hover {
border-color: transparent;
background-color: #444;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
color: #FFF;
}
#main-nav > li > a {
display: block;
letter-spacing: 1px;
padding: 10px 20px;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-right: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.07);
color: #FFF;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
position: relative;
z-index: 99997;
box-shadow: inset 0px -19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 21px;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
-ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.responsive-nav-wrapper {
position: relative;
display: block;
display: none;
z-index: 9999;
}
#responsive-nav , .responsive-nav-wrapper #resp-menu {
background: #363D40;
}
#responsive-nav {
border-top: none;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
padding-right: 20px;
z-index: 99999999999999;
}
#responsive-nav:hover, .responsive-nav-wrapper.responsive-active #responsive-nav {
background: #498AB8;
    }
#responsive-nav:hover .nav-icon, .responsive-nav-wrapper.responsive-active #responsive-nav .nav-icon, #responsive-top-nav .nav-icon:hover, .responsive-top-nav-wrapper.responsive-active #responsive-top-nav .nav-icon {
border-top-color: #FFF;
border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
#responsive-nav:hover .text-nav, .responsive-nav-wrapper.responsive-active .text-nav {
color: #FFF;
}
.responsive-nav-wrapper.responsive-active #resp-menu {
display: block;
z-index: 9999;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#responsive-nav {
display: block;
background: #363D40;
border-top: solid 5px #666;
border-top-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
padding-right: 40px;
min-height: 40px;
margin-bottom: 0 !important;
box-shadow: inset 0 -20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.responsive-top-nav-wrapper {
width: auto;
display: none;
z-index: 9999;
height: 40px;
}
#responsive-top-nav {
border-top: none;
position: relative;
padding-right: 60px;
height: 40px;
z-index: 9999;
}
#responsive-top-nav .nav-icon {
margin-top: 11px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.responsive-top-nav-wrapper #top-resp-menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 15px;
width: auto;
background-color: #fff;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.98);
border: solid 1px #e7e7e7;
}
#top-resp-menu #top-menu-ul, #top-resp-menu ul {
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#top-resp-menu li a {
display: block;
width: 100%;
color: #888;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
padding: 8px 70px 8px 15px;
border-bottom: solid 1px #e9e9e9;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.text-nav {
float: left;
padding-left: 20px;
line-height: 40px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 13px;
color: #eee;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#responsive-nav .nav-icon, #responsive-top-nav .nav-icon {
margin-top: 12px;
display: block;
border-bottom: 10px double #aaa;
border-top: 3px solid #aaa;
height: 4px;
width: 25px;
float: right;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
border-top-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.responsive-nav-wrapper #resp-menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 44px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #363D40;
}
#resp-menu li, #top-resp-menu li {
display: block;
float: none;
}
#resp-menu ul, #top-resp-menu ul, #top-resp-menu ul li, #resp-menu li {
width: 100% !important;
}
#resp-menu li a {
display: block;
color: #FFF;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
padding: 8px 20px 8px 15px;
border-bottom: solid 1px #444;
border-left: solid 5px #444;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.responsive-top-nav-wrapper {
    display: none;
```

and this is the HTML.

Please have a look and help me.

```
<div class='inner-wrap'>
<nav class='menu-main-navigation-container'>
<ul id='main-nav'>
<!-- Main Menu -->
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Blog</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Lifestyle</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Travel</a>

<ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Sub-Menu 2</a>

<ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
                    </ul>

                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

<li><a href='#'>Archives</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Sample Page</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
<div style='clear:both'/>
</ul>           </nav>
```

Comment: What's happening exactly? are the items not being displayed correctly or are they simply not being displayed? If you could provide a working jsfiddle with your issue it'd be easier to give you a solution

Comment: @EmilioVenegas they are simply not being displayed. The thing is that there is a section of the CSS that I need to write and this will run the HTML and give me sub-menus, sub-sub-menus etc. What that section is in the CSS i dont know.
this is exactly where i got the code from http://way2themes.com/blogger-templates/spraymag.zip

Comment: You should be very careful with selectors like `#main-menu ul li:first-child`. This means "any li that is a first child of its parent", and not, as I suspect you mean, "only the very first li".

Comment: Also, the classes and ids in your HTML have preciously little in common with the CSS. You might want to look into that.

Comment: And you have an absurdly high z-index. Do you really think browsers are required to treat something like that correctly? And the `<div style='clear:both'/>` at the end of the ul is wrong, in more ways than one. In addition, the indentation makes it look as though there are a different level of submenus than there really are. (This is not an error per se, but it makes it harder to debug.)